# visual studio lines that been modified

Tags: .net, visual-studio, add-in, add-on

I'm Using TFS and changing different lines of code in different Clases.
Is there a tool that can color the lines that been modified in the current changeSet before I do checkin ?

I know there's the Compate option but it's clumsy.
I just want that the modified lines will be marked once I do a change.
Example I maid in PaintBrush :
[image]

Comment: Tools such as Visual Assist or Resharper show the modified lines with a mark on document margin, but only as long as you keep the document opened. But I guess you're looking for more.

Comment: I have Resharper installed but I don't see that it show what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do a diff on each file.  The only other thing I know is the power tools addin which add some stuff to the solution explorer so you can see only the files you have modified.

Comment: Thank, I know theses things, looking for something better.